# are body and form considered as divs?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I was learning how to include external html file to the current html and I wrote simple code like this

```
<html>
<head runat="server">
    <title>Untitled Page</title>
    <script type ="text/javascript"   src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" > 
       $(document).ready(function(){
        {
            $("div").load("test.html") ;
        }
       });

   </script>
</head>
<body>
    <form id="form1" runat="server">
       <div id = "div1" >
       </div>
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

test.html content is

```
<h1>done!</h1>
```

the output is

> done!
>
> done!
>
> done!

when I replace

```
  $("div").load("test.html") ;
```

with

```
$("#div1").load("test.html") ;
```

or

```
$("form").load("test.html");
```

the output is

> done!

I really would like to know how it works

Comment: My answer is body and form not considered as div.

Comment: Right click the area and look at the elements as they are live.

Comment: And all your code output done!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

When using ASP.net there are additional divs created by serverside code. You need to try `inspect element` of `F12` to check exactly how many divs you have in your page after it has been rendered.

When you use 
`$("form").load("test.html");` you will get only one output because you have only one form in your asp.net page (which is by default)

Also when you use
`$("#div1").load("test.html");` You have only one element with that ID hence only that div will be populated with the result of your ajax call.

Hope  this helps